# .NET List.Find runtime error

Tags: c#, data-structures, treeview

I'm building a custom data structure to hold a TreeView so that I can serialise it. This bit is irrelevant and is background but I'm putting it here.

I have a CustomNode class and the treeview is going to be held in a `List<CustomNode>`:

```
private class CustomNode
    {
        public CustomNode()
        {}

        public CustomNode (string name)
        {
            NodeName = name;
        }
        public string NodeName { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public CustomNode parent;
        public List<CustomNode> children;
    }
```

This is the relevant problem I'm trying to solve. At a point in my code I want to find the parent of a particular CustomNode so I do:

```
   CustomNode customNode = new CustomNode();
   //initialise properties of customNode (below)
   . 
   .
   .
   CustomNode customNodeParent = new CustomNode();
                            customNodeParent = listOfCustomNodes.Find(_customNode => (_customNode.Index == node.Index && _customNode.Level == node.Level));
   customNode.Index = customNodeParent.children.Count;
```

The last line throws a **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** exception. I don't understand why this is happening.

**EDIT:** There is another problem. At the point where I call:

```
customNode.Index = customNodeParent.children.Count;
```

customNodeParent is null. I see what's happening. It's not finding the node. Need to fix that.

Comment: Is `customNodeParent` null or `customNodeParent.children`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your declaration of `CustomNode`, change

```
public List<CustomNode> children;
```

to

```
public List<CustomNode> children = new List<CustomNode>();
```

With your current code, you are saying "a `CustomNode` has a field named `children`, which is of type `List<CustomNode>`", but this field's **value** never gets set, so when a `CustomNode` is created, `children` is `null`.

By making the above change, you are saying "when first created, a `CustomNode`'s `children` is an actual object, a new `List<CustomNode>`". Since this is an actual object, rather than `null`, it is safe to ask it for its `Count`.

Comment: Oh...I had this before but must have accidentally deleted it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `customNodeParent.children` is null.

You need to instantiate `customNodeParent.children` before you try to use it.

Easiest done on the declaration, then perhaps in the constructor and as a last resort, in your instantiation code outside the class.